# Grouping rows with similar values

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to get a count of error types sorted by the users who experienced the error by name. However, username and systemname are not differentiated in my data. According to my data, systemname is just a username.

I would like to make a bar graph where systemname is on the x-axis and count of Errors in on the y-axis. However, I'd like to group all the users (users are names that are not System1 or System2) into one username.

So if I have data that looks similar to this:

```
 UserName  Error Code  
 ---------------------
 System1      abc
 System1      123
 System2      123
 UserABC      abc
 UserEFG      abc
 UserABC      xyz
```

My graph might look like:

```
3|              x
 |
2|  x           
 |
1|        x
 |_________________
    S1    S2  Users
```

Is there a way to do this in Power BI desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a custom column that strips off the ending of the `UserName`.

In the query editor, choose Custom Column under the Add Column tab and use a formula like this:

```
if Text.Contains([Username], "User") then "User" else [Username]
```

[image: Custom Column]

When you load that table, you can create a visual with this new column on the x-axis and a count of the errors on the y-axis.

[image: Bar Chart]

Comment: Thank you! My first hour or so of Power Query & Power BI. I didn't realize we have access to the same functions in Excel. This lead me to the Microsoft Power Query reference page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same in "DAX", and not in M Query, then you can use the below formula.

```
Category = IF(
              ISERROR(
              SEARCH("User", UserTable[UserName])
              ),
              UserTable[UserName],"User"
             )
```

[Click to view the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKhwR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Select Transform tab and we have first option Group by select that

[image]

We can able to select the rows in which we need to group
[image]

Once filter option selected and give ok then we will get new table which contain group by values
[image]